# Basic Calculator

Tags: java, calculator

Im having problems with my program. the program displays the first JOption message dialog box, but when you input a value, it fails to display the second dialog box??

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class javaCalculator 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    String operation;


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"please enter the first number");
    num1 = input.nextInt();

    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"please enter the second number");
    num2 = input.nextInt();


    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter operation");
    operation = input.next();

    if (operation.equals ("+"))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"your answer is" + " " + (num1 + num2));
    }
    if  (operation.equals ("-"))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"your answer is" + " " + (num1 - num2));
    }

    if (operation.equals ("/"))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"your answer is" + " " + (num1 / num2));
    }
    if (operation.equals ("*"))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"your answer is" + " " + (num1 * num2));
    }


}


}
```

Comment: Then operation is likely *not* equal to any of the operator strings - what *is* it really? (Also, consider using `System.out.println` for a console app .. you're reading from the console, so might as well write to it :-/)

Comment: And, how *is* this program being being started? With `java` or `javaw`?

Answer (score 1):

Read the numbers from the dialog output instead of from System.in:

```
String firstNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"please enter the first number");
if (firstNumber != null) {
    num1 = Integer.parseInt(firstNumber);
}
```

Scanner is unnecessary in your code.

Comment: @user2037720 Was it useful? Please accept or say something :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using that sample code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Hw4_3 {

    private static boolean flag;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        do {
            String[] expression = getTask();
            double result = calculate(expression);
            display(expression, result);
            repeat();
        } while (flag);
    }

    public static String[] getTask()
    {
        String bleh = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter what you would like to calculate: ");
        String[] tokens = bleh.split(" ");
        return tokens;
    }

    public static double calculate(String[] data)
    {
        double num1 = Double.parseDouble(data[0]);
        double num2 = Double.parseDouble(data[2]);
        double result = 0;
        if(data[1].equals("+"))
        {
            result = add(num1, num2);
            return result;
        }
        else if(data[1].equals("-"))
        {
            result = subtract(num1, num2);
            return result;
        }
        else if(data[1].equals("*"))
        {
            result = multiply(num1, num2);
            return result;
        }
        else 
        {
            if(num2 == 0)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sytax error, divide by zero");
            }
            result = divide(num1, num2);
            return result;
        }


    }

    public static double add(double num1, double num2)
    {
        return num1 + num2;
    }

    public static double subtract(double num1, double num2)
    {
        return num1 - num2;
    }

    public static double multiply(double num1, double num2)
    {
        return num1 * num2;
    }

    public static double divide(double num1, double num2)
    {
        return num1 / num2;
    }

    public static void display(String[] data, double result)
    {
        if(data[1].equals("/") && data[2].equals("0"))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, data[0] + " " + data[1] + " " + data[2] + " = " + result);
        }
    }

    public static void repeat()
    {
        int bleh = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "More?",null, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if(bleh == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
        {
            flag = false;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Have a good day.");
        }
        else
            flag = true;

    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (And this one would also benefit from proper indentation.)